# Difference between setOnXXX() method and addEventHandler() JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to learn JavaFX event handling. I found that we can register event by two ways.

One is convenience method like `setOnAction(EventHandler)`, `setOnMouseClicked(EventHandler)`

The second is by using `addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, EventHandler)`

But I'm confused what is the difference between them? how decide which one will be suitable?

I have tested and registered two event handler using both methods and both are working fine.

```
Button btn = new Button("Click Me One!");
    btn.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent e){
            System.out.println("Mouse Entered on Click Me One");
        }
    });

    btn.setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent e){
            System.out.println("Mouse Exited from Click Me One");
        }
    });


    Button btn2 = new Button("Click Me Two!");
    btn2.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent e){
            System.out.println("Mouse Entered on Click Me Two");
        }
    });
    btn2.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent e){
            System.out.println("Mouse Exited from Click Me Two");
        }
    });
```

Here is the output after checking.

```
Mouse Entered on Click Me One
Mouse Exited from Click Me One
Mouse Entered on Click Me Two
Mouse Exited from Click Me Two
```

I also checked by defining event handler.

```
Button btn2 = new Button("Click Me Two!");
        // Define an event handler
        EventHandler<InputEvent> handler = new EventHandler<InputEvent>() {
            public void handle(InputEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Handling event " + event.getEventType()); 

            }
        };
        btn2.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED, handler);
        btn2.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED, handler);

        btn2.setOnMouseEntered(handler);
        btn2.setOnMouseExited(handler);
```

Output:

```
Handling event MOUSE_ENTERED
Handling event MOUSE_ENTERED
Handling event MOUSE_EXITED
Handling event MOUSE_EXITED
```

Comment: Your code has nothing to do with your question.  Nowhere in your code are you using `addEventHandler`.  (For the record, you should always use setOnAction for a Button, never setOnMouseClicked.  Not every user activates buttons using the mouse.)

Comment: @VGR I have updated the code please check now.

Comment: If nothing else, the explicit event properties serve to enumerate exactly which events are valid for a particular class.

Comment: @VGR can you explain more? examples will be bonus for me.

Comment: Imagine that there were no setOn… methods at all.  How would you know that some classes, like Button, support `EventType<Action>`?  Each Node subclass would have to document the additional event types it supports… which would be fine if developers regularly read the documentation of a class, and the documentation of all classes from which it inherits, before using it, but in reality they rarely do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After testing myself I got the exact point what is the meaning of **There can be only one handler of same type with convenience method**. So I'm going to answer of my own question.

There are two main difference I found between `setOnXXX()` method and `addEventHandler`

**1: The event that you register with `addEventHandler()` will execute first. Here is the Example.**

```
Button btn = new Button("Hover Me!");

btn.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Handling event with Convience Method"); 
    }
});
btn.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Handling event with addEventHandler"); 
    }
});
```

Output:

```
Handling event with addEventHandler
Handling event with Convience Method
```

After reading **James_D**'s comment I have added paragraph from [original doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/processing.htm) for the 1st difference.

> A node can register more than one handler. The order in which each
>   handler is called is based on the hierarchy of event types. Handlers
>   for a specific event type are executed before handlers for generic
>   event types. For example, a handler for the KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED event
>   is called before the handler for the InputEvent.ANY event. The order
>   in which two handlers at the same level are executed is not specified,
>   with the exception that handlers that are registered by the
>   convenience methods described in Working with Convenience Methods are
>   executed last.

**2:** The second difference is that you can add Multiple handler with Same `EventType` ( as I used Mouse_Entered Event) using `addEventHandler();` but in case of `setOnXXX();` last registered event handler will execute. Here is the Example.

```
Button btn = new Button("Hover Me!");

btn.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Handling event 1 with Convenience Method"); 
    }
});
btn.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Handling event 2 with Convenience Method"); 
    }
});
btn.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Handling event 1 with addEventHandler"); 
    }
});

btn.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Handling event 2 with addEventHandler"); 
    }
});
```

Output:

```
Handling event 1 with addEventHandler
Handling event 2 with addEventHandler
Handling event 2 with Convenience Method
```

As you see I registered two event handler using both ways. But in convenience method's way the last event handler executed. To complete the answer let me copy the paragraph from **jns**'s answer.

> So if you need only one `EventHandler` it makes no difference which
>   method you use. However, if you need to **apply several EventHandlers**
>   for the same `EventType` you have to add them using `addEventhandler`

Comment: Is the order in which they are executed actually documented (i.e. can you rely on that functionality), or is that just what happens in the current implementation you have tested on?

Comment: Here you can find http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/processing.htm `The order in which two handlers at the same level are executed is not specified, with the exception that handlers that are registered by the convenience methods described in Working with Convenience Methods are executed last.`

Comment: You should add that into the answer to make it complete

Comment: @James_D Yes I have added.

Comment: This is wrong - `but in case of setOnXXX(); last registered event handler will execute.` When you set handler via setOnXXX() this handler is saved in ObjectProperty onXXX. So, one property can have only one handler. That's why when you call setOnXXX second time you just replace the previous handler by this new one.

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at the javadoc for `Node` [setEventHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setEventHandler-javafx.event.EventType-javafx.event.EventHandler-) (which gets called from `setOnXXX`):

> Sets the handler to use for this event type. **There can only be one such handler** specified at a time. This handler is guaranteed to be
>   called as the last, after handlers added using
>   addEventHandler(javafx.event.EventType, javafx.event.EventHandler)}.

So if you need only one `EventHandler`it makes no difference which method you use. However, if you need to apply several `EventHandlers` for the same `EventType` you have to add them using `addEventhandler`

Comment: javadoc link will be helpful. can you give me the link from where you got this paragraph? and I already explain above I can add multiple event handler with both techniques.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setEventHandler-javafx.event.EventType-javafx.event.EventHandler-

Comment: where is written setEventHandler called from setOnXXX? I'm confused can you give me sample code to describe difference between them? and `There can only be one such handler specified at a time` I already added two events with set methods then why it's working?

Comment: Sets the handler to use for **this event type** (e.g. MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED). There can only be one such handler (**for this event type**). Try to add several listeners for **the same** event type using e.g. `setOnMouseExited`  and you will see only the last one added will get called

Comment: I already added. and both are executing. `setOnMouseEntered` and `setOnMouseExited` Please read my code in question. can you update you answer with code example?